# failed to install ros-indigo-freenect-launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i'm using Ubunti 14.04 LTS, before i installed `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-launch`, it worked succesfuly. but i think after i uninstall some file with `sudo apt-get remove <my package>` which  is the word that include `openni` and `freenect` in it. After that, i restart and try to install the package again , it said that :

```
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers amd64 1.11.7-0trusty-20150729-0024-+0000
Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (140.211.166.134), connection timed out
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-camera-info-manager amd64 1.11.7-0trusty-20150729-0102-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-depth-image-proc amd64 1.12.14-0trusty-20150806-2000-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-image-proc amd64 1.12.14-0trusty-20150806-1958-+0000
Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers/ros-indigo-camera-calibration-parsers_1.11.7-0trusty-20150729-0024-+0000_amd64.deb  Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (140.211.166.134), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-camera-info-manager/ros-indigo-camera-info-manager_1.11.7-0trusty-20150729-0102-+0000_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-depth-image-proc/ros-indigo-depth-image-proc_1.12.14-0trusty-20150806-2000-+0000_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-image-proc/ros-indigo-image-proc_1.12.14-0trusty-20150806-1958-+0000_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:
```

so, what's wrong with my system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220480/failed-to-install-ros-indigo-freenect-launch/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you are experiencing a network issue. Can you ping packages.ros.org? I do not think it is related with your apt-get remove command. You can try with another internet connection or router if possible.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-06**:
Yea. I think it's because of my unstable network. Thankyou

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-06**:
Glad to hear you solved your issue.